# Is it possible to keep Bluetooth on when I activate airplane mode on my laptop running Windows 11?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-11, airplane-mode

So on my iPhone it remembers if I had Bluetooth on when plane mode was disabled and when I enable plane mode Bluetooth stays on. I was wondering if the new Windows 11 has that same feature. I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure if I have to turn on anything.

Comment: Why don’t you just skip using airplane mode and only disable your cellular service? You can also just try it.

Comment: @Ramhound On windows I don't have cellular, just Wi-Fi. Thing is it's easier to enable or disable plane mode using my keyboard with fn+f2 key rather than having to open action center and do it there, and every time I do that I have to enable Bluetooth again and connect my devices which is frustrating. Also I couldn't find a button or fn key that does the same for Bluetooth like with plane mode, it would've been way easier if there was.

Comment: @Ramhound Thirdly is sometimes the Wi-Fi misbehaves and when it does the Wi-Fi icon turns into a globe icon which is the same icon that shows when WiFi is off and that's confusing because I then have to open action center to check if WiFi is on or it's just misbehaving which tends to happen a lot and tends to get frustrating real quick. It would be great if I could just turn on plane mode with my fn key when I want to turn off Wi-Fi and have Bluetooth stay on all the time. This is difficult with windows 10 and felt like torture and so I was wondering if the feature is available in windows 11.

Comment: Airplane mode is only required for your cell phone. WiFi being enabled but not connected to a network isn’t a safety concern.  Of course you provided none of that detail in your question

Comment: @Ramhound my question was simple and straightforward. I wanted to make it as easy as possible to understand that’s why it was short and to the point.